# What is the `end+1` line doing here?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following bit of MATLAB code:

```
degree = 6;
out = ones(size(X1(:,1)));
for i = 1:degree
    for j = 0:i
        out(:, end+1) = (X1.^(i-j)).*(X2.^j);
    end
end
```

I'm not sure I see how the `end+1` index is functioning. There are no previously defined variables called `end` in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `end` as a subscript is equivalent to writing the index of last element in the array in the specified dimension, as stated in the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html):

> The `end` function also serves as the last index in an indexing expression.
>   In that context, `end = (size(x,k))` when used as part of the `k`th index. Examples of this use are `X(3:end)` and `X(1,1:2:end-1)`.**When using `end` to grow an array, as in `X(end+1)=5`, make sure `X` exists first.**

In your case (highlighted in bold), `out(:, end+1)` means that the matrix `out` is growing in the second dimension with each iteration of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

`end` is a keyword in Matlab which can be used an array index and always means the last element in that dimension.

So `out(:, end)` is the last column.  `out(end, :)` is the last row.  `out(1, end)` is the last element in the first row.

And here, when `out(:, end+1)` refers to a column past the end of the matrix, the assignment automatically grows the matrix, adding the just-computed vector as a new column on the right.