# Where is the documentation for the "end" keyword in Octave? (for indexing)

Tags: octave

I was trying to figure out what the following Octave code does:

```
degree = 6;
out = ones(size(X1(:,1)));
   for i = 1:degree
    for j = 0:i
        out(:, end+1) = (X1.^(i-j)).*(X2.^j);
    end
end
```

I wasn't sure what the **end+1** meant in Octave until I found the answer for Matlab here:
[What is the `end+1` line doing here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876682/what-is-the-end1-line-doing-here)
The accepted answer links to the Matlab official documentation which is very clear:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html

I'm trying to find the documentation for this same keyword in the Octave documentation but I can't seem to find it.
I've searched in the Documentation tab (Octave 5.1.0), using the function index and the search tab to no avail although I see it used in several documentation pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Octave documentation, which seems to be categorized more by usage than keyword, on [Index Expressions](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Index-Expressions.html#index-end_003aend_003a-and-_003aend) is also as explicit:

> In index expressions the keyword `end` automatically refers to the last entry for a particular dimension. This magic index can also be used in ranges and typically eliminates the needs to call size or length to gather array bounds before indexing.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try `help end` in Octave. That will give you what you're looking for.

In Octave and Matlab, there are two help-finding functions, `help` and `doc`. (`doc` is what pops up the GUI documentation browser.) And they will give you *different results* for the same topics! So always try both when you're looking for something.

And there's nothin' wrong with looking through the Matlab doco and Stack Overflow answers for this. Octave is pretty compatible with Matlab, so anything you find there for basic language functionality (except for `string`s, `table`s, and `datetime`s) will apply to Octave as well.

Comment: Excellent advice!